# Here is a SQL join with GROUP BY and ORDER BY that will generate a report of # orders, BUT it will not work

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Here is the schema:

```
create table Retailer (
    row bigint,
    id uniqueidentifier,
    name varchar(255),
    domainName varchar(MAX)
)

create table SalesPeople
( Row bigint not null identity,
  ID uniqueidentifier not null,
  Retailer_ID uniqueidentifier not null,
  FirstName nvarchar(255) not null,
  LastName nvarchar(255) not null,
  EmailAddress nvarchar(511) ,
  PhoneNumber nvarchar(255) 
 )

orders (
    row bigint,
    id uniqueidentifier,
    Retailer_ID uniqueidentifier,
    salesperson_id uniqueidentifier,
    prod_id uniqueidentifier,
    date datetime
)
```

We are designing a query that will report the salespeople and the number of orders they have generated for a particular retailer. Also, if Mark and Bill are tied, but Bills's orders are more recent, Bill will need to show up on top of Mark. Also, the one who generated the most orders needs to show up on the very top of the list.

So say for Retailer EBAY, the sales data states that John did 2000 orders in January of 2012, and Bill did 999 orders in Jan 2010 and 1 order in August 2013, and Mark did 1000 orders in June of 2013, and Marry did 700 orders in July 2010 and 150 orders in July 2013. The output would look like this:

```
 Sales Person        #ofOrdersCreate    
 John                 2000
 Bill                 1000
 Mark                 1000
 Marry                 850
```

The query we have tried is:

```
select s.firstname + ' '+s.LastName ,   COUNT(o.id) from Orders o 
  inner join SalesPeople s on s.ID=o.Retailer_ID 
  inner join Retailers r on r.id = o.retailer_id
   where r.name='EBAY'
   group by s.firstname + ' '+s.LastName
    order by o.date
```

But we get errors from the join statement above because we can not order the data since it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues:

1. Because your grouped results will contain multiple possible dates you need to either include the field in the order by (which does not work for what you are attempting to accomplish) or use an aggregate function on the group of results that are returned (like `sum` or in your requirement, `max`).
2. Your `group by` should be on the collective columns `s.firstname, s.lastname` not an aggregation of them.

So fix like this:

```
select s.firstname + ' '+s.LastName ,   COUNT(o.id) from Orders o 
inner join SalesPeople s on s.ID=o.Retailer_ID 
inner join Retailers r on r.id = o.retailer_id
where r.name='EBAY'
group by s.firstname, s.LastName
order by count(o.id) DESC, max(o.date)
```

Comment: Question: this query orders like 1, 2, 3... how do I get it to order highest to lowest? I tried DESC, but it didn't work?

Answer (score 1):

Please try now:

```
select s.firstname + ' '+s.LastName ,   COUNT(o.id) from Orders o 
inner join SalesPeople s on s.ID=o.Retailer_ID 
inner join Retailers r on r.id = o.retailer_id
where r.name='EBAY'
group by s.firstname + ' '+s.LastName
order by COUNT(o.id)
```